# Why am I getting Syntaxerror for this while loop?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I was working on my code and I got error for this else statement:

```
while i<=end:
    x.append(i)
    if i<=radiussph:
        ex=((int(den(i)))*i)/(3*e)
    else:
        ex=((radiussph**3)*int(den(i)))/(3*(i**2)*e)
    o.append(ex)
    i+=10**(-5)
```

But once I removed it the append statement is getting the error. (Actually by pattern, the line of code that lie in that line-18 is getting a Syntaxerror. Even after skipping that line I'm getting the same error in the next line).

**Full code:**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

end=float(input("Enter the end point:"))**(10**(-3))
m=[i for i in range(0,int(end),2)]
def den(a):
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if a<m[i] and a>m[i-1]:
            return (10-6*i)
        if a==m[i]:
            return (10-6*(i+1))
radiussph=float(input("Enter the radius of the sphere in millimetres:"))*(10**(-3))
o=[]
x=[]
i=1*10**(-5)
e=8.854*(10)**(-12)
while i<=end:
    x.append(i)
    if i<=radiussph:
        ex=((int(den(i)))*i)/(3*e)
    else:
        ex=((radiussph**3)*int(den(i)))/(3*(i**2)*e)
    o.append(ex)
    i+=10**(-5)
plt.plot(x,o)
plt.show()
```

This is happening irrespective of ide. So what causes this problem.

Comment: Check your parentheses. If you are using an ide, then the syntax highlighting should give you some clues.

Comment: @quamrana I'm getting that error even after it

Comment: Sorry, that's the fault of python. It is notoriously bad at exactly pinpointing errors. Nevertheless it's the parentheses. Did you see the answer from Talon?

Comment: @quamrana no....

Comment: You can still upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line has a non-matched opened parenthesis.

```
ex=((int(den(i))*i)/(3*e)
#  ^ There
```

You'll need to remove it or put a closing one where you need it